# Error when request IP is not in range

Tags: http

I am working on security implementation and I have developed the `IP` filtering security application. So I wondered which `HTTP` error code should be returned if the user's `IP` is not in expected range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if your Application is running on a Server..the following will be appropriate.....

```
403 - Forbidden
```

A 403 status code indicates that the `client cannot access the requested resource`. That might mean that the `wrong username` and `password` were sent in the request, or that the `permissions on the server do not allow what was being asked`.

Answer (score 1):

403 - forbidden

Details here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html